# Having a "out of global stack" in prolog

Tags: prolog, planning, failure-slice

Hey guys I have a fairly simple question about Prolog.

```
%on(Block,Object).
% clear(Object).
block(b1).
block(b2).
block(b3).

place(p1).
place(p2).
place(p3).
place(p4).
state1([clear(p2),clear(p4),clear(b2),clear(b3),on(b1,p1),on(b2,p3),on(b3,b1)]).
% visual state1
% b3
% b1    b2
% =  =  =  =
% 1  2  3  4     <----Positions
% can(Action,Condition).
% adds(Action,AddRelationship).
% deletes(Action,DeleteRelationship).
% move(Block,From,To).
can( move( Block, From, To), [ clear( Block), clear( To), on( Block, From)]) :-
  block( Block),      % Block to be moved
  object( To),           % "To" is a block or a place
  To \== Block,          % Block cannot bå moved to itself
  object( From),         % "From" is a block or a place
  From \== To,           % Move to new position
  Block \== From.        % Block not moved from itself
adds(move(X,From,To),[on(X,To),clear(From)]).
deletes(move(X,From,To),[on(X,From),clear(To)]).
object(X):-
      place(X)
      ;   
      block(X).
% plan(State,Goals,Plan,FinalState).
plan(State,Goals,[],State):-
    satisfied(State,Goals).
plan(State,Goals,Plan,FinalState) :-
    append(PrePlan,[Action|PostPlan],Plan),
    select(State,Goals,Goal),
    achieves(Action,Goal),
    can(Action,Condition),
    plan(State,Condition,PrePlan,MidState1),
    apply(MidState1,Action,MidState2),
    plan(MidState2,Goals,PostPlan,FinalState).
% satisfied(State,[]).
satisfied(State,[Goal|Goals]):-
    member(Goal,State),
    satisfied(State,Goals).
select(State,Goals,Goal):-
    member(Goal,Goals),
    not(member(Goal,State)).
achieves(Action,Goal):-
    adds(Action,Goals),
    member(Goal,Goals).
apply(State,Action,NewState):-
    deletes(Action,DelList),
    delete_all(State,DelList,State1),!,
    adds(action,AddList),
    append(AddList,State1,NewState).
delete_all([],_,[]).
delete_all([X|L1],L2,Diff):-
    member(X,L2),!,
    delete_all(L1,L2,Diff).
delete_all([X|L1],L2,[X|Diff]):-
    delete_all(L1,L2,Diff).
```

After running this in the compiler it says it has no problems but when i try to execute the command
`plan(state1,on(b1,b2),Plan,FinalState).`

it just says out of global stack. Can someone help me to fix this

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can't you provide a minimal example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you use SWI, simply say `check.` You will get a warning that `adds(action,_)` will always fail.

Comment: Why are you calling `append` so early with all variable arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to look at this:

```
plan(State,Goals,[],State):- false,
    satisfied(State,Goals).
plan(State,Goals,Plan,FinalState) :-
    append(PrePlan,[Action|PostPlan],Plan), false,
    select(State,Goals,Goal),
    achieves(Action,Goal),
    can(Action,Condition),
    plan(State,Condition,PrePlan,MidState1),
    apply(MidState1,Action,MidState2),
    plan(MidState2,Goals,PostPlan,FinalState).

?- plan(state1,on(b1,b2),Plan,FinalState).
```

Since this program already loops, the very same program will loop with the additional **`false`** goals removed. You need to address this problem first. See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response and it looks like you're completely right, but since this is my first "contact" with prolog I am very bad at it can you suggest what might fix the problem in my case